# C# Http server using StreamSocketListener, the option "InputStreamOptions.Partial" returns data incomplete

Tags: c#, sockets, http, networking, tcp

First of all I am working on a Windows Universal app project. I have created a simple tcp listener using `StreamSocketListener`. The data comes from a device attached to my local network. This devices sends out Http, and Http/Xml packets randomly.

I have created the socket listener as follows:

```
StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();

public async void HttpServer()
{
   listener.ConnectionReceived += (s, e) => ProcessRequestAsync(e.Socket);
   HostName hostName = new HostName("192.168.0.150");
   NetworkAdapter thisAdapter = hostName.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter;
   await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("5400", SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket, thisAdapter);
}
```

And this is the callback function when data is available:

```
private const uint BufferSize = 12000;

private async void ProcessRequestAsync(StreamSocket socket)
{

    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();

    using (IInputStream input = socket.InputStream)
    {             
        byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
        IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
        uint dataRead = BufferSize;
        while (dataRead == BufferSize)
        {
            await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.None);
            request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, (Int32)buffer.Length));
            dataRead = buffer.Length;
         }

    String message = request.ToString();

    ExampleTextLabel.Text = message;

    ....

}
```

**Here is the problem:**

I have set the BufferSize = 12000. This is because, so far the maximum data length I have recieved was below 11500. The length of the content is in the HTML header (CONTENT-LENGTH) but I am not sure how to read the header before the line:

```
await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

When I use the option InputStreamOptions.None, the message I receive is delayed by one packet. In other words when the device sends out packet 1, it does not write it to the following text label:

```
ExampleTextLabel.Text = message;
```

When packet 2 arrives, the ExampleTextLabel shows the message from packet 1. I know this because I am using Wireshark to observe the incoming packets.

On the other hand, if i use the option InputStreamOptions.Partial, there is no delay. I receive the packets as it appears in Wireshark. However the problem with this solution is that most of the time the packets are corrupted (incomplete).

Could someone explain me the problem here, and if there are any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, have you succeeded creating generic http server on StreamSocketListener? I'm working on universal app as well and I need http server too. We can start github project.

Comment: Yes my HTTP server is working as expected, however I didn't make it generic. Seems like there aren't many examples around, so I will make it generic and share it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question,

InputStreamOptions.Partial is an asynchronous read operation completes when one or more bytes is available.

This means sometimes it will end the read operation without completing the packet. I did the following changes to the code above to get it working (not the actual code, just comments to give ideas):

```
while (allDataRead)
{
    await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.None);
    request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, (Int32)buffer.Length));
    dataRead = buffer.Length;

    //make sure the data read contains the html header, otherwise loop again
    //until you can extract the HTML header.
    //Get the content length from the HTTP header.

    //If the buffer size does not match the content length + html header length,
    //then loop again to get the remaining packets until the buffer length
    //matches the content length + html header length

    //If the content length matches the buffer length then you have received the packet completely.
    //allDataRead=true to exit the loop.

}
```